# NodeJS - express reloads page after res.render()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I use MongoDB and NodeJS (with Express Framework).

**What I actually do:**

- Crawl some data in the MongoDb
- Render this data.

**What I want to do:**

Filtering for specific items.

The filtered results are all correct, but my problem is that the page will be rendered twice.

How can I prevent that?

I have got a main contextroot which actually looks like that:

```
app.get('/main', auth, function(req, res) {
    getItems(req, res, function(results) {
        renderResults(req, res, results);
    });
});
```

And this is my renderresult function:

```
function renderResults(req, res, results) {

  console.log("In Rendermethode arrived:");
  console.log(results.items);

    res.render('pages/main', {
        offerings: results.items,
        ownUser: {
            id: req.session.user || ""
        },
        filterObj: {
            isActivated: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined',
            filterFor: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined' ? results.filterObj.filter : "",
            filterText: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined' ? results.filterObj.filterText : ""
        }
    });
}
```

What I do is a post request in the frontend:

```
$("button.doSearch").on("click", function(e) {
    var dFilter = $("div.filterDropdown button").attr("value") || "",
        dFilterText = $("input.searchterm").val() || "";

    $.post("/search", {
            filter: dFilter,
            filterText: dFilterText
        },
        function(data, status) {
        });
});
```

And this is the backend snippet for the search:

```
app.post('/search', auth, function(req, res) {
    console.log("Filterrequest received.");
    getItems(req, res, function(results) {
        renderResults(req, res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your `button.doSearch`  button in a form and is that a submit button?  If so, you need to use `e.preventDefault()` in the button event handler to prevent the default form submission and automatic page reloading.  And, keep in mind that `$.post()` does not change what is displayed in the browser.  If you intend for the browser display to change, you will have to do that with Javascript yourself.  Or, if you want the form to post by itself and rerender the browser page by itself, then use a regular form submission, not a Javascript form submission.

Comment: Hi. No, it is not a submit button..

Comment: Then, I guess I don't understand what problem you're asking about or what you expect the outcome to be.  The response to the HTTP POST will be sent when you call `res.render()`. What else are you expecting?

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem is, that all "normal" results of the database are rendered, and not the filtered results. That is because I can see in my console.log output, that the rendering is called two times... and I don't understand why. For me it seems that the page is reloaded after my  .render call.

Comment: Please show us the HTML surrounding your button. That symptom usually means that you are BOTH sending an ajax post AND the browser is sending a generic form post.  The page reload happens from the browser form post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are rendering the same view twice, because you are calling `renderResults` function in both requests get and post

**Problem:**

The first HTTP request you made is a GET request to `/main` url, express handles it and renders the `pages/main` view

The second request is an xhr post to `/search` url, express will handle it and render the same view `pages/main` (the whole page)

It makes no sense to render the whole page to your AJAX object, Instead you can render a JSON object and update your page using native javascript OR JQuery

**Solution:**

Rendering different kind of data according to the request type (xhr **OR**  not):

```
function renderResults(req, res, results) {

    var result = {
        offerings: results.items,
        ownUser: {
            id: req.session.user || ""
        },
        filterObj: {
            isActivated: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined',
            filterFor: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined' ? results.filterObj.filter : "",
            filterText: typeof results.filterObj !== 'undefined' ? results.filterObj.filterText : ""
        }
    };

    if (!req.xhr) {

        return res.render('pages/main', result);

    }

    res.json(result);
}
```